# Extract name of return variable from Python function

Tags: python

I have a python function x that returns some module
x():
return y

I would like to parse the file x is located in and learn that "x returns this thing called 'y'". I have no idea how.

I'm not trying to get the type of the return type, just what the programmer calls exactly what is being returned.

Comment: What do you need that for?

Comment: I am trying to write a plugin that documents endpoints in an API written in pecan. Certain functions return functions that they route to, it would be nice to see the name of the functions being returned.

Comment: See this builtin module - https://docs.python.org/3/library/parser.html

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to call the functions and check `returned_object.__name__`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Use the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#module-ast)

```
import ast                                                                                                  
                                                                                                            
def extract_return(file, fname):                                                                            
    for x in ast.walk(ast.parse(open(file).read())):                                                        
        if not(isinstance(x, ast.FunctionDef)):                                                             
            continue                                                                                        
        if not(x.name == fname):                                                                            
            continue                                                                                        
        for b in x.body:                                                                                    
            if isinstance(b, ast.Return):                                                                   
                if isinstance(b.value, ast.Name):                                                           
                    yield b.value.id
```

This defines a function which takes some python source's filename and a function name `fname` (your "`x`") and yields each identifier returned by function `fname`. Here, *I assume that you are only interested in `return` statements that occur at the first level of function `x` and consequently, I don't visit subexpressions.* Also, I'am using `yield` because in more general cases this could work like a filter which could be composed with other ones. In more complex cases, it can be preferable to subclass `ast.NodeVisitor`.

This is equivalent in size with the regex approach but far more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could hack something together with regexes pretty quickly.

Pseudocode:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
def findReturns(program_string):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    func_name = None
    for line in re.findall('def .+\w|(?<=return ).+', program_string):
       if line.startswith('def '):
           func_name = line[4:]
           continue
       result[func_name].append(line)
    return result
```